# How to map a list of objects into an array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, map-function

I have an array of objects that I need to reformat into a list of arrays in a specific format.

I need my list to be formatted like this

```
list: [
        [ "B", "A" ],
        [ "F", "E" ],
    ]
```

But the closest I have come is this

```
list: ["B A", "F E"]
```

using this code

```
const itemList = [
    {"ProductName":"A",
        "Sku":"B",},
    {"ProductName":"E",
        "Sku":"F",}
];

const newList = itemList.map(item => `${item.Sku} ${item.ProductName}`);

console.log(newList);
```

How would I map this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create array with the values inside map:

```js
const itemList = [
    {"ProductName":"A",
        "Sku":"B",},
    {"ProductName":"E",
        "Sku":"F",}
];

const newList = itemList.map(item => [item.Sku, item.ProductName]);

console.log(newList);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use destucure for each item and map it to array of these values:

```js
const itemList = [
  {
    ProductName: 'A',
    Sku: 'B'
  },
  {
    ProductName: 'E',
    Sku: 'F'
  }
];

const newList = itemList.map(({ProductName, Sku}) => [
  Sku,
  ProductName
]);

console.log(newList);
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep things simple, I would use Object.values as such:

```
const newList = [];
itemList.map(item => newList.push(Object.values(item)));
```